# Debug print from a bootstrapped Firefox4 extension

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

I'm rewriting a Firefox extension to be bootstrapped (restartless). I've patched rdf with a node < bootstrapped >. Then I introduced file "bootstrap.js":

```
function startup(data, reason) { dump("startup") }
function void shutdown(data, reason) {}
```

The extension was installed visually correctly and it stopped to work (that means correctness too). But I have no clue how to debug my extension without debug prints: dump() does not work (jconsole stays empty), alert() too. I'm not sure even the function startup() had been invoked actually. How to make sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [part 5 of my restartless firefox addon series, on logging](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/4/1/restartless-firefox-addons-part-5-logging): http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/4/1/restartless-firefox-addons-part-5-logging

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And for the articles too.

Comment: Another "bootstrapped" topic could be: how a developer would be informed about runtime JS-errors while they aren't reported into js-console normally. There is a possibility to cover code into try/catch statements and do reports via logStringMessage() but this is not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that window.dump is not enabled. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.dump

Comment: a bootstrap.js file does not have a window.